# Looking for references for NBG theory meant for the working mathematician (not for someone interested at Foundations of Mathematics)

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

As most mathematicians, I've always used sets as the main tool for doing mathematics. My knowledge of the subject is limited to what I've learned from Halmos's *"Naive Set Theory"* and, for years, it was more than enough for me, as I don't have any interest at working at the field of Foundations of Mathematics. But, recently, the subject of surreal numbers caught my attention and for the first time in my life I had to deal directly with Classes. I picture them as a generalization for the concept of set, allowing the existence of "special sets" (Proper Classes) which may not be members of any "set" (Class), and so far this basic understanding has been enough to follow the proofs at the books. Still, when I am not tutored by the books, I feel often afraid of doing something illegal for not knowing exactly what I am allowed to do with classes.
Therefore, I am looking for references of NBG theory which are meant for the working mathematician (not for people who want to become experts at Fundations of Mathematics). Basic texts teaching me the ability to work with classes without risks.
So far, all the material I've found (Zaring, for example) is too technical for me. What I am looking for is something like Halmos' book, but with classes. Is there anything similar? Where can I get a solid knowledge about classes without being annoyed by irrelevant (for me) technical details? Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are interested only in the operations you can do with classes in the sense of category theory (eg products, quotients etc), then you can rest in the knowledge that NBG classes form a Boolean pretopos with subobject classifier. It additionally has exponentials for sets.  See eg my question and answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231087/3835

Comment: @David Roberts, despite a certain introductory book in category theory is currently one of my objects of desire, currently my knowledge in the field is nearly zero. And, right now, I am looking for something that I can quickly learn.

Comment: If you just want to look up the axioms of NBG and MK, you may refer to the first some pages of Kameryn Williams' doctoral dissertation. However, the dissertation is definitely inclined to foundational interests, so not adequate for your purpose.

Comment: @AndersonBrasil sorry, I think it would be reasonable to check out the other answers and their reference. The point is that you can do cartesian products of a pair of classes (and so finitely many), quotients by equivalence relations, carve out subclasses by formulas, form disjoint unions of a pair of classes (and by extension finitely many) and these behave just in the same way they do for sets. You can form the class of all functions from a set to a class. This is most of what you need to know, not the nitty-gritty of exactly which axioms are available.

Comment: @HanulJeon, ty for the reference.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, the problem is that right now I don't have ANY knowledge of category theory. So I would probably take much more time that way, as it would require me learning at least the the basic notions of the theory. Of course, this option has a big  advantage: I would acquire some knowledge of the subject (which is probably something advisable to any mathematician). But right now I don't have the time for this, I need to quickly learn to deal with Classes. That is why I am ruling out this option. But I really do appreciate your replies. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anderson ok, fair enough. One to come back to, then. Sorry it wasn't as useful for you.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, @DavidRoberts. And I am pretty sure that your tip, recorded at this thread, will be useful for someone else in here.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a reason to prefer NBG over MK (Morse-Kelley theory of sets and classes)? If not, you might look at the development of MK in the Appendix (if I remember correctly) of Kelley's book "General Topology". It's surely intended for the working mathematician, since (again, if I remember correctly) Kelley had originally intended this book to be titled "What every young analyst should know".

Comment: As a working mathematician, I am agnostic about foundation models =p.
As I've said, my knowledge of set theory is basically Halmos' book, which is essentially ZFC without the axiom of regularity. My preference for NBG was only because (as far as I know) NBG ressembles ZFC more than MK ressemble ZFC. So I felt that it would be easier for me to adapt to NBG. Still, it is nice to have options. I will try to find the reference you gave me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndersonBrasil I’d actually argue that MK is syntactically more similar to ZFC then NBG, even though it is a bit stronger in terms of consistency strength.

Comment: I've finally got a copy of Kelley's book. The appendix is indeed very interesting and might be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for: Elliot Mendelson, *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, fifth ed., CRC Press, Boca Raton (2010). I think there is a 6th edition as well.

Another possibility would be: Smullyan, R. and Fitting, M. (2010): Set theory and the Continuum Problem, Dover Publications, New York.

For Mendelson NBG includes the axiom of global choice and for Smullyan and Fitting it just includes the axiom of choice.

Comment: I took a quick look at the Smullyan-Fitting and the second chapter seems that is going to be very helpful. Thanks a lot.